# Moving group of objects at the same time in canvas

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

My problem is that I have no idea how to implement group of objects, in my situation, group of rectangles moving all at the same time. Well, I implemented easily moving one rectangle with specific direction which you can see below from my code. Also I tried to add an array with group of rectangles. So again my question is how to implement group of rectangles (3 rows 3 columns, 9 of them, for instance) to move the same way how my one rectangle is moving in the code below????? So basically very right side of group and very left side of the group will hit the border while column in the middle of 3X3 will stay moving between two columns of 3X3.....Any help will appreciated. Thank you...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spaceman Invaders</title>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.fillStyle="black";
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(30, 100, 20 , 20);

        var posx = 27;
        var posy = 100;
        var go_right = true;
        var go_down = false;
             if (canvas.getContext) {

               /*   var array = [];

                  array.push(new Shape(20, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(20, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(20, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(80, 120, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 0, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 60, 50, 50, "red"));
                  array.push(new Shape(140, 120, 50, 50, "red"));*/


        setInterval( function() {



            if (!go_down) {
                if(posx < 250 && go_right) {
                    posx += 3;
                } else if(posx < 30) {
                    go_right = true;
                    go_down = true;
                } else if(!go_right) {
                    posx -= 3;
                }else {
                    go_right = false;
                    go_down = true;
                }
            } else {
                //if(posy <= 30)
                posy += 5;
                go_down = false;
            }


            context.fillStyle="black";
            context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);


            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillRect(posx, posy, 20 , 20);
            context.fill();


            }
        , 20);

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="screen" width="300" height="500"/>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store the x,y position of each rectangle. You may create an new class for this. I've made you an example:

```
var Alien = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.posx = 30 + x*30;
    this.posy = 90 + y*30;
    this.go_right = true;
    this.go_down = false;
    this.perrow = 3;
}

Alien.prototype.move = function() {
         if (!this.go_down) {
            if(this.posx + (this.perrow-1-this.x) * 30 < 250 && this.go_right) {
                this.posx += 3;
            } else if(this.posx < 30 + this.x*30) {
                this.go_right = true;
                this.go_down = true;
            } else if(!this.go_right) {
                this.posx -= 3;
            } else {
                this.go_right = false;
                this.go_down = true;
            }
        } else {
            //if(posy <= 30)
            this.posy += 30;
            this.go_down = false;
        }
}

Alien.prototype.draw = function(context) {
    if(this.x == 0) {
        context.fillStyle = "red";
    } else if(this.x == 1) {
        context.fillStyle = "yellow";
    } else {
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
    }
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillRect(this.posx, this.posy, 20 , 20);
    context.fill();
}
```

Then you can update the position and draw each object separately in a loop inside of your intervall callback.

EDIT:
Now the objects move downwards all at once.

You can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6F4d/3/

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I meant the moving of 9 rectangles together....So basically you will have 3 rows and 3 columns. And they move together not after each other...@0nth3l3ft

Comment: if i get you right it should be a group like shown in this http://jsfiddle.net/Z6F4d/2/ but the movement downwards should be at the same moment. Right?

Comment: well basically very right side of 3X3 should hit right side of the black canvas then 3X3 object goes down altogether as one. After that 3X3 goes left and hit left side of black canvas by very left side of  of 3X3. Then 3X3 object goes down as one and goes right and hit right side of the black canvas and etc. Sorry for dump explanations. Beginner here.....

Comment: no problem, but try to descripe it more the next time. here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6F4d/3/